# Convert row with columns of data into column with multiple rows in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, database-normalization

I have a row of data as follows:

```
            header1      header2      header3      header4      header5
row key     datavalue1   datavalue2   datavalue3   datavalue4   datavalue5....
```

so basically, I have a denormalized data set where the datavalues may or may not be empty on a row-by-row basis.  I need to normalize them.

ie

```
12345678    NULL         10           3            NULL         14
```

would become:

```
12345678   header2   10
12345678   header3   3
12345678   header5   14
```

I could do this by using a paste special transform, but I have thousands of rows and I'd need to make sure that I get the right row key for each.  furthermore, each row has a bunch of descriptives associated with it that I need copied over with each datavalue.

What is the easiest way to convert each row of columns such that I have multiple rows of a single column with all non-empty datavalues plus the associated datavalue reference?  I need to be able to pivot the dataset.

Comment: Personally, I would use VBA code to parse through the list. This is easy to say for someone who is familiar and comfortable with writing VBA code, but to someone who is new to VBA, it can appear very challenging. How comfortable are you with VBA? Would you like to see a VBA solution?

Comment: Added VBA tag in order to open the question up to some experts in that area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have five "header" columns, enter these formulas

```
H1: =OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW()-1)/5)+1,0)
I1: =OFFSET($A$1,0,IF(MOD(ROW(),5)=0,5,MOD(ROW(),5)))
J1: =INDEX($A$1:$F$9,MATCH(H1,$A$1:$A$9,FALSE),MATCH(I1,$A$1:$F$1,FALSE))
```

Copy H1:J?? and paste special values over the top.  Sort on column J and delete anything that's a zero.  If you have legitmate zeros in the data, then you first need to replace blank cells with some unique string that you can then delete later.

If you have more columns, then replace the '5' in all the above formulas with whatever number you have.

Comment: Thank you.  Your formulas are the simplest solution posted (and one I vaguely understand!) so I'm planning to start with this approach before digging into the depths of VBA.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!  These formulas work wonderfully.  I had to make some mods and figure out exactly what was going on, but they saved me from having to learn VBA on the fly!

Comment: Is there a way to modify the formula in J1 to reference multiple columns in the MATCH?  I am finding instances where the same person can have multiple leaves over different periods of time.  I'd like to match on 2 columns so that I can be sure to pull the right data; otherwise, I get double-counting of the first leave type.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that part of what you are trying to do is to "de-pivot" a pivot table.  I've found this tip to be a tremendous help when I've had to do similar tasks:  http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/creating_a_database_table_from_a_summary_table/

Note that in Excel 2007, you can get to the old Excel 2003 pivot table wizard using the keystrokes Alt+D, P .

Answer (score 1):

Excel has a transpose feature which may address your needs.  It's pretty hidden and a bit clumsy but likely easier than delving into VBA.  Here's an excerpt from Excel 2007 Help:

> Blockquote
>   Switch (transpose) columns and rows
>   Show AllHide All
>   If data is entered in columns or rows, but you want to rearrange that data into rows or columns instead, you can quickly transpose the data from one to the other.

For example, the regional sales data that is organized in columns appears in rows after transposing the data, as shown in the following graphics.

1.On the worksheet, do the following:
To rearrange data from columns to rows, select the cells in the columns that contain the data.
To rearrange data from rows to columns, select the cells in the rows that contain the data.
2.On the Home tab, in the Clipboard group, click Copy .

Keyboard shortcut  To copy the selected data, you can also press CTRL+C.

Note   You can only use the Copy command to rearrange the data. To complete this procedure successfully, do not use the Cut  command.

3.On the worksheet, select the first cell of the destination rows or columns into which you want to rearrange the copied data.
 Note   Copy areas (copy area: The cells that you copy when you want to paste data into another location. After you copy cells, a moving border appears around them to indicate that they've been copied.) and paste areas (paste area: The target destination for data that's been cut or copied by using the Office Clipboard.) cannot overlap. Make sure that you select a cell in a paste area that falls outside of the area from which you copied the data.

4.On the Home tab, in the Clipboard group, click the arrow below Paste, and then click Transpose.
5.After the data is transposed successfully, you can delete the data in the copy area.
 Tip   If the cells that you transpose contain formulas, the formulas are transposed and cell references to data in transposed cells are automatically adjusted. To make sure that formulas continue to refer correctly to data in nontransposed cells, use absolute references in the formulas before you transpose them.

For more information, see Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed references.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

I would create a VBA macro that loops through each row and output the data to another page.  This would let you create your pivot table in the new page once the data has been outputed.

Not sure how familiar you are with VBA, but this could pretty easily be done by loading the data into an array (or collection of objects if you really want to do it correctly) and writing it back out.

Here is a link to a good VBA document.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/isvvba/thread/d712dbdd-c876-4fe2-86d2-7d6323b4262c

**Edit**

Please note this is not meant to be a fully working solution but really a generic framework to help you in the right direction.

As a generic example that does a lot of what you would need to do (not the best way, but probably the easiest for a beginer), something like this should get you started, although it is hard to say without seeing more of your worksheet.

```
Sub RowsToColumns ()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim srcWrkSheet As Worksheet
  Dim destWrkSheet As Worksheet
  Dim excelData as pExcelData
  Dim srcRowNumber As Long
  Dim srcRolNumber As Long
  Dim destRowNumber As Long
  Dim destColNumber As Long

  SET srcWrkSheet = Sheets("YourSourceWorkSheetName")
  SET destWrkSheet = Sheets("YourDestinationWorkSheetName")

  srcRowNumber = 1
  srcColNumber = 1
  destRowNumber = 1
  destColNumber = 1

  'Loop until blank row is encountered in column 1
  Do
    destWrkSheet.Cells(destRowNumber ,1).Value = "Header 1 " & srcWrkSheet.Cells(srcRowNumber,srcColNumber )
    destWrkSheet.Cells(destRowNumber ,1).Value = "Header 2 " & srcWrkSheet.Cells(srcRowNumber ,srcColNumber)

    srcRowNumber = srcRowNumber + 1
    srcColNumber = srcColNumber + 1
    destRowNumber = destRowNumber  + 1
  Loop Until srcWrkSheet .Cells(rowNumber, 1).value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: ugh.  I was really hoping to avoid VBA.  I have zero familiarity with VBA.  Will read the link though.

Comment: If you turn on the record macro function and perform the task manualy once and post the code, I will try to trim it up real quick or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: "I was really hoping to avoid VBA." - I felt that way for a long time, but the truth is, learning VBA is wonderful for doing excactly what you want to do.  Excel functions usually take a lot of hacking to get just right.

Comment: @Irwin, I think your code has lots of issues: you need to initialize row numbers and column numbers to be 1. You really should use nested loops for both rows and columns. You need a separate counter for the rows on your destination worksheet, else you'll only write one value per key. Good idea for VBA use, though...just make sure it's good VBA use :)

Comment: @bmccormack, you are absolutely correct.  I wrote that code in the editor as a framework to work off of, but I should have used more care.  I am correcting it now.

Comment: @bmccormak, I would have likely done this myself by populating a class or at a minimum a custom type.  By running this, it should provide (now) some of what VBA can do.

Comment: My thanks to everyone who replied.  I have a lot of information here to process and I can't guarantee I won't be back with more questions!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a possible solution in VBA.  I think this will really help.  Here are a few things you should know about my code.

- You'll need to put this code in a code module in VBA (the same place where Macros go)
- Look at what I named the sheets: Original and Normalized.  You'll either want to change your sheet names or the code
- I'm checking for values with a string field of `NULL`. If the cell is empty, you'll want to check for `If IsEmpty(rngCurrent.Value) Then` instead.

'

```
Sub NormalizeSheet()
Dim wsOriginal As Worksheet
Dim wsNormalized As Worksheet
Dim strKey As String
Dim clnHeader As Collection
Dim lngColumnCounter As Long
Dim lngRowCounterOriginal As Long
Dim lngRowCounterNormalized As Long
Dim rngCurrent As Range
Dim varColumn As Variant

Set wsOriginal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Original")     'This is the name of your original worksheet'
Set wsNormalized = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Normalized") 'This is the name of the new worksheet'
Set clnHeader = New Collection

wsNormalized.Cells.ClearContents        'This deletes the contents of the destination worksheet'

lngColumnCounter = 2
lngRowCounterOriginal = 1
Set rngCurrent = wsOriginal.Cells(lngRowCounterOriginal, lngColumnCounter)

' We'll loop through just the headers to get a collection of header names'
Do Until IsEmpty(rngCurrent.Value)
    clnHeader.Add rngCurrent.Value, CStr(lngColumnCounter)
    lngColumnCounter = lngColumnCounter + 1
    Set rngCurrent = wsOriginal.Cells(lngRowCounterOriginal, lngColumnCounter)
Loop

'Here we'll reset our Row Counter and loop through the entire data set'
lngRowCounterOriginal = 2
lngRowCounterNormalized = 1
lngColumnCounter = 1

Do While Not IsEmpty(wsOriginal.Cells(lngRowCounterOriginal, lngColumnCounter))

    Set rngCurrent = wsOriginal.Cells(lngRowCounterOriginal, lngColumnCounter)
    strKey = rngCurrent.Value ' Get the key value from the current cell'
    lngColumnCounter = 2

    'This next loop parses the denormalized values for each row'
    Do While Not IsEmpty(wsOriginal.Cells(lngRowCounterOriginal, lngColumnCounter))
        Set rngCurrent = wsOriginal.Cells(lngRowCounterOriginal, lngColumnCounter)

        'We're going to check to see if the current value'
        'is equal to NULL. If it is, we won't add it to'
        'the Normalized Table.'
        If rngCurrent.Value = "NULL" Then
            'Skip it'
        Else
            'Add this item to the normalized sheet'
            wsNormalized.Range("A" & lngRowCounterNormalized).Value = strKey
            wsNormalized.Range("B" & lngRowCounterNormalized).Value = clnHeader(CStr(lngColumnCounter))
            wsNormalized.Range("C" & lngRowCounterNormalized).Value = rngCurrent.Value
            lngRowCounterNormalized = lngRowCounterNormalized + 1
        End If

        lngColumnCounter = lngColumnCounter + 1
    Loop
    lngRowCounterOriginal = lngRowCounterOriginal + 1
    lngColumnCounter = 1    'We reset the column counter here because we're on a new row'
Loop



End Sub
```