# Rendering STAR schema in Excel (a 2-Dimension table)

Tags: excel, vba, data-warehouse, pivot-table

<sup>Please move to an appropriate forum if it doesn't belong here.</sup>

I've a data feed that represents some multidimensional data in star schema.
e.g. /Products /SalesYear /SalesContact /Region /Salesdata

Now I want to render this data in a simple tabular view

example

```
                            2005   2006   2007
Product1                    
 Category1                  27m$   30m$   35m$
 Category2                  9m$    1m$    11m$
Product2                    
 Category1                  27m$   30m$   35m$
 Category2                  9m$    1m$    11m$
```

Are there any standard algorithm or techniques that can be used to display this kind of data?

**[EDIT]**

What I need essentially is an efficient method to build an in-memory cube like powerpivot does but at a smaller scale.

Comment: Could you explain a bit? Where is the data? In a warehouse/database?

Comment: it is coming from an OData feed. e.g. Products is a feed. http://server/data.svc/Products will return a list of products. All the above mentioned entities are associated with the salesdata feed.

Comment: One way to achieve this is to write an OLEDB OLAP provider over OData feed and then use excel pivot table to render the data. But it doesn't look like a practical option.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use a modified version of this answer by @Dick Kusleika: [Convert row with columns of data into column with multiple rows in Excel 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784407/convert-row-with-columns-of-data-into-column-with-multiple-rows-in-excel-2007/1785562#1785562). Note that this solution does not the nested rows under Product1/Product2 that you have above, but my guess is you could pretty easily modify the solution to handle two row headings: column `A` would contain product name and column `B` would contain the category.

---

**EDIT:** I misunderstood and thought you were trying to get the data *out* of that format, not *in to* that format.

If you have Excel 2010, the [PowerPivot plugin](http://www.powerpivot.com/) can consume OData fields directly (found the answer on the [OData.org consumers page](http://www.odata.org/consumers). If you have an older Excel, you might still be able to pull the data in with `Get External Data From Web`. You may need to throw a proxy page (ASP.NET, PHP, whatever you're comfortable with) in-between that understands JSON and transform it into an HTML table. `Get External Data From Web` will definitely understand how to read data from a standard table.

Once you have the data in a normalized sheet in Excel, it should only be a matter of inserting a Pivot Table that uses that range as it's data source.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a more generic way of rendering the relational data (similiar to a pivot table). Number of dimensions or hierarchy may extend to a larger number in which case the logic will become too complex. I can do a cell by cell write but if there is lots of data it will be very slow as well.

Comment: Yes you are right. PowerPivot provides tha capabilities I'm looking for. I need to build a similiar type of extension for Excel. Now I've two options A) either to build an in-memory cube and use OLAP data provider to connect to the Pivot Table or B) find-out a standard algorithm to render the data in a Pivot table like structure. First option seems too heavy to build (though if possible I'd like to build a light weight version of the PowerPivot vertex engine) so I'm actually looking for the option B.