# Excel VBA to transpose multiple columns to single column multiple rows

Tags: excel

I'm a beginner in VBA. Even after trying to find a solution and searching through all the forums, i was not able to find the correct way of dealing with this. Here's my problem:

Data ( in sheet1 )

```
a    a1    a2    a3  a4  
b    b1    null      b3  b4  b5  
c    c1    c2    c3  
....
```

Required output ( in sheet2 )

```
a  a1  
a  a2     
a  a3
a  a4
b  b1  
b  null  
b  b3
b  b4
b  b5  
c  c1  
c  c2  
c  c3  
....
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow. Maybe you could share some (failing) code, so people can start their answer with that and guide you to your (mis-)understanding?

Comment: I tried Normalization...got stuck with some reference error...I tried this too...similar to this but it isnt generic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784407/convert-row-with-columns-of-data-into-column-with-multiple-rows-in-excel-2007)

Comment: This is my first attempt at stack-overflow. Please pardon me if I'm not following the correct etiquette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add column labels (may be deleted later) apply the process described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-flatten/20543651#20543651) and filter ColumnC to delete rows blank in that column.

Comment: This is something i hadn't encountered. Pretty much useful but the processing done is quite different from the required output.

Comment: FOr me its like..b a1 b1 in the first row, b a2 null in the second..b a3 b3 in the third, b a4 b4 in the fourth, b blank b5 in the fifth, and it starts all over again taking "c" in the next iteration..